# Laravel 5.1 - `php artisan migrate` is giving 'PDOException'

Tags: mysql, laravel, pdo, mamp

I know this is a duplicate question however whatever I tried, unfortunately no luck. (To add, I am using MAMP)

I believe I successfully setup the database connection because, using the registration form (*Auth/register*), after submitting the form, I was getting the error `PDO Exception: Driver not found` before, but after changing to my MAMP to `PHP 5.5.17` from the default(`PHP 5.6.1`), I started getting error: `SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel.users' doesn't exist`, which I believe shows that the database connection is working and it's just the *'users table'* is not created.

**Here starts my problem**. When I try to use `php artisan migrate` or `migrate:{anything}` in the terminal, it's throwing the error:

> [PDOException]
>     could not find driver

But what I want to do is to use `php artisan migrate` to be able to create tables and migrate them.

---

---

#### Things I have tried:

- I added `<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>` to if pdo files are successfully installed.
  I get the result:

[image]

so I think it seems okay.

---

- People were talking about opening `/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.1/conf/php.ini` and adding `extension=pdo_mysql.so` in the code, but I have mine already placed there.

---

- When I try `php -i | grep PDO` in the project root (/MAMP/htdocs/proj), I got:

`PDO
PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => sqlite
PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled`

- `php -i | grep Conf` and `php --ini also outputs:

`Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.1/conf
Loaded Configuration File:         /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.1/conf/php.ini` but `php artisan migrate` still throwing the same error

## SOLUTION:

I chose MAMP to use version 5.5.17 instead of 5.6.1 in the browser (from MAMP Preferences), however this time terminal was running the 5.6.1. What I did was first checking `which PHP` command and then, running the `nano ~/.bash_profile` command; and editing the version document. Now everything is up and running :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you see in the browser is that you have PDO enabled for PHP running through apache. But this does not mean you have it enabled for PHP running through CLI (in fact they are using two separate ini files). To confirm that you can try:

```
php -i | grep PDO
```

And you will see it is missing or not enabled. So what you need to do is to find which php.ini is using the PHP running through CLI and add the PDO module there:

```
php -i | grep Conf
```

It will output something like:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

Comment: I edited the OP (things I have tried part). Please take a look

Comment: @senty I also edited my answer please take a look, and let me know the result.

Comment: Yes, I see the output: `Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini` but `php artisan migrate` still throwing the same error `[PDOException]         
  could not find driver`

Comment: @senty Did you added the PDO module to that ini file?

Comment: `extension=pdo_mysql.so` already exists in my php.ini file :/

Comment: @senty What you can try is to take the ini file from the `phpinfo()` from the browser and replace the CLI ini file with it.

Comment: Do you mean taking the php.ini file from `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.1/conf/php.ini`, copying and replacing it with another php.ini? What do you mean by CLI ini file?

Comment: Yes, because at least you know it properly load PDO.

Comment: Last question, where is my CLI file located. I just now edited the OP again, when I use `php -i | grep Conf` I get `bla bla bla bla Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.1/conf
Loaded Configuration File => /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.1/conf/php.ini
Configuration`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83900/discussion-between-senty-and-shaddy).